# How can I wait for my animations to finish in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to get my animation to finish before doing anything else however I don't know any methods on how to do that so I use @RodrigoAbreu answer in this question: (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1812575/wait-for-animation-to-finish-4.html). However it doesn't work. I looked online and they say to use an animation event however I don't understand how to use them. Are there any other methods?

Edit: I added a debug.Log and had it display the length of `(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length + anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime);         anim.SetBool(booleanName, false);` and it does have a value.

The method:

```
   IEnumerator PlayAnim(Animator anim, string booleanName)
    {
        anim.SetBool(booleanName, true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length + anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime);        
        anim.SetBool(booleanName, false);        
    }
```

How it is being used:

```
public void MultAttack(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent, GameObject self, bool MultiAttack, float inRange, float inView)
    {
        if (!MultiAttack) return;
        
        if (random == 0) random = Random.Range(1, 5);

        if (random == 1)
        {                    
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 2)
        {
            if (HasParameter("Attack2", anim))
            {                
                StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack2"));
                random = 0;
                return;
            }           
                                   
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 3)
        {
            if (HasParameter("Attack3", anim))
            {                
                StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack3"));
                random = 0;
                return;
            }
                        
            StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
            random = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (random == 4)
        {
            BlockPlayer(playerPos, anim, agent, inRange, inView, self);
            random = 0;
            return;
        }
        
        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
        random = 0;
        return;       

    }

public void BlockPlayer(GameObject playerPos, Animator anim, NavMeshAgent agent, float inRange, float inView, GameObject self)
    {        
        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Block"));                
        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "BlockAttack"));            
        StartCoroutine(PlayAnim(anim, "Attack"));
        
        state = State.Attack;
    }
```

Comment: There's not enough information to solve the problem here. The problem should be scribed in enough detail to understand what's happening. "doesn't work" doesn't describe anything useful, it only means your expectations aren't met. Is any animation playing at all? Are all animations playing without stopping? Does it freeze your computer? Does it email a embarassing letter to your old math teacher? It would help to include a [mre] in the question including how to set up the scene, animations, input as necessary. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Nothing in your post even hints at the use of animation events. What did you try to do with animation events that "didn't work"? You can also use events from a custom state behaviour to determine when a particular animation state has finished, if you'd rather not use animation events.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.